# How to resolve PermGen Out of memory exception issue in in Weblogic 10.3.5 while performing multiple deployments and undeployments?

Tags: java, weblogic, jvm-arguments, permgen

How to resolve PermGen Out of memory exception issue in in Weblogic 10.3.5 while performing multiple deployments and undeployments? I have increased Xmx to 768 mb to java arguments..even after I'm facing the same issue? Any help would be appreciated ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have ClassLoader/PermGen leaks and want to get rid of them, you can use the [ClassLoader Leak Prevention library](https://github.com/mjiderhamn/classloader-leak-prevention).

In case you want to track down the leaks [this blog series](http://java.jiderhamn.se/2011/12/11/classloader-leaks-i-how-to-find-classloader-leaks-with-eclipse-memory-analyser-mat/) will be of help.